# How do you activate mods for the new Skyrim: Special Edition for Xbox One?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, mods, xbox-one

So I just got the new Skyrim game for Xbox One and I can't figure out how to get the mods to work. I've already downloaded a couple and when I loaded up the game they didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You first need to have a Bethesda account, [head here to login or create one.](https://account.bethesda.net/en/login)

Once you are logged in, you should be able to see the mods section in the menu [(or click on this link which has the xbox one filter applied)](https://mods.bethesda.net/#en/workshop/skyrim/view-all?categories=Crafting&platform=XB1&sortBy=published).

Once you are there, you can select what mods you want to apply to your Skyrim on that console by clicking on the desired mod and then clicking on add to library.

[image]

Once you have it added to your library, go back to your console and from the menu screen, select Mods.  This will take you to the Bethesda.net login.
[image]

Now you should see the mods you added to your library in the previous steps, under My Library.  You can also search and add mods directly from this screen.

[image]

To enable the mod, click on the desired mod and click download.

[image]

After it completes the download, it will automatically enable it. **Note: Achievements will be disabled if any mods are turned on**

[image]

Under each mod, you can Favorite, Enable/Disable, Delete, Rate, and Report.

Once you are ready, backout to the menu and you should see this prompt:

[image]

The game will reload with the mods you have enabled.